# Returning rows based on search parameters works except order changes?

Tags: postgresql

I need to return entries from a table based on parameters in an array. This is working but the results come back in a different order:

```
select * from my_table where internal_id = any(array[
  'one@gmail.co.uk',
  'two@gmail.co.uk',
  'three@gmail.co.uk'
]);
```

Result:

| internal_id | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| three@gmail.co.uk | stuff |
| one@gmail.co.uk | stuff |
| two@gmail.co.uk | stuff |

Answer (score 0):

One way is to sort by the position of the internal_id in the array.

```
select * 
from my_table 
where internal_id = any(array['one@gmail.co.uk','two@gmail.co.uk','three@gmail.co.uk'])
order by array_position(array['one@gmail.co.uk','two@gmail.co.uk','three@gmail.co.uk'], internal_id);
```

Another option is to use a JOIN, but that might be slower:

```
select mt.*
from my_table mt
  join unnest(array['one@gmail.co.uk',
                    'two@gmail.co.uk',
                    'three@gmail.co.uk']) with ordinality as val(id,idx) 
    on mt.internal_id = val.id
order by val.idx;
```